# Grouping data by an certain rank in Python

Tags: python, parsing, text

I have a file that looks like this. The numbers in the segment are x and y coordinates.[The text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlkTp.png)

I want to only read the records with rank=1 and store the coordinates in a x and y list. So I need to read and save the rank and the number of points. If the program knows the number of points it knows how much coordinates it have to read and store.

I have already the following code but I am stuck at the point that I don't know  how I tell the program that it needs to read the number of points until the new segment.

```
file = "/Users/yuval/Desktop/test1.txt"

x = []
y = []

with open(file, "r") as f:
    for lines in f:
        line = lines.split()
        if(line[0] == "segment"):
            rank = int(line[3])
            points = int(line[5])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your first `if` block, you can use an additional `if` block to append to your lists when `rank==1`.

```
x = []
y = []

rank = None
with open(file, "r") as f:
    for lines in f:
        line = lines.strip().split()
        if(line[0] == "segment"):
            rank = int(line[3])
            points = int(line[5])
            continue
        if rank==1:
            x.append(float(line[0]))
            y.append(float(line[1]))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer!

Comment: Minor update: I swapped the `int` to `float` in the append statements